# If a set E is contained in a Borel measurable set B, and the Lebesgue measure of B\E is 0, then is E a Lebesgue measurable set?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

In many proofs of theorems I find this statement "*If exist $B$, Borel measurable set, which contains a set $E$, and $|B \setminus E|=0$, then $E$ is Lebesgue measurable because of the completeness of the Lebesgue measure*".
I had to report the question because I asked the wrong question.

Comment: Did you mean repost, rather than report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $K=B\setminus E$. Since $K$ has mesure $0$ it's Lebesgue measurable. Since $E=B\cap K^c$ then $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've spent hourse trying to understand this, thank you so much.